# Postgresql group by and jsons just in one array

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL Query like this below

```
select json_build_array(
            json_build_object(
                 'entegrator_name', e2."name",
                 'provider_name', p."name",
                 'table1_count', count(t1.id)
        )
    )
    FROM table1 AS t1
    JOIN entegrators AS e2 ON e.entegrator_id = e2.id
    JOIN providers AS p ON e.provider_id = p.id
    GROUP BY e2."name", p."name"
```

result like this below

```
[{"entegrator_name": "entegrator_name", "provider_name": "provider_name", "table1_count": 6}]
[{"entegrator_name": "entegrator_name1", "provider_name": "provider_name1", "table1_count": 6}]
[{"entegrator_name": "entegrator_name2", "provider_name": "provider_name2", "table1_count": 6}]
...
```

But expected like this below, so in one row and one array.

```
[{"entegrator_name": "entegrator_name", "provider_name": "provider_name", "table1_count": 6},
 {"entegrator_name": "entegrator_name1", "provider_name": "provider_name1", "table1_count": 6},
 ...]
```

how can I do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query you need two aggregations:

- `COUNT` to count your ids,
- `JSON_AGG` to make a json array out of all json records

As long as aggregation functions cannot be nested, they can't be found within the same scope. Use a subquery to solve this problem.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e2."name"    AS e2_name, 
           p."name"     AS p_name, 
           COUNT(t1.id) AS cnt_t1_id
    FROM table1 AS e
    JOIN entegrators AS e2 ON e.entegrator_id = e2.id
    JOIN providers AS p ON e.provider_id = p.id
    GROUP BY e2."name", p."name"
)
SELECT json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                 'entegrator_name', e2_name,
                 'provider_name', p_name,
                 'table1_count', cnt_t1_id
            )
       )
FROM cte
```

Comment: aah sorry. Your ```JSON_AGG``` correct using. I wrote wrong. it works so perfect. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON_AGG() aggregate function in the query like this:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'entegrator_name', e2."name",
        'provider_name', p."name",
        'table1_count', COUNT(t1.id)
    ) ) FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN entegrators AS e2 ON e.entegrator_id = e2.id JOIN providers AS p ON e.provider_id = p.id GROUP BY e2."name", p."name"
```

Comment: it gives this error ```ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested```. that error caused by ```'table1_count', COUNT(t1.id)```